# Android Webview don't load my FPDF link in webview

Tags: java, android, pdf, webview

I am using web-view in my native android application. But the issue I am facing is that I have a PHP file generatePDF.php which takes sessions, parameters from URL and output pdf file on that URL. The issue is that when I pass that URL to webview directly it doesn't load pdf in webview but instead if I pass direct pdf file link through anchor link it loads.

```
WebView wv = findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
wv.loadUrl("http://localhost/generatePDF.php?uid=1");
```

Above code don't load pdf. But if i add some anchor tag and add above path in href then it opens that pdf.

```
wv.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://localhost/generatePDF.php?uid=1");
```

I tried like above and it loads pdf directly but it doesn't pass the sessions.

Kindly guide how can I load my generatePDF file directly in web-view

Comment: Is your generatePDF using Javascript Code? You need to manually enable JavaScript for a WebView. ```wv.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true```

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` has no ability to display PDFs. Either:

- Use something like [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to be able to parse and render PDF in a `WebView`, or
- Use [a library](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) to render a PDF as its own view

See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html) for more on this subject.